# SQLiteDatabase concurrent convenience update, query not updated android

Tags: java, android, sqlite

I am trying to update the field of an entry in an `SQLiteDatabase` using the db.`update(...)` method, but it seems the value is not stored. I've tried the convenience db.`query(...)` method right after the update method has been executed and found that the entry is still stored as before the `update`.

Is there some sort of background work that I must wait for before the query, or where am I going wrong? I am using a singleton extended `SQLiteOpenHelper` (`dbHelper`) as recommended in [SQLite DB accessed from multiple threads](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6225374/sqlite-db-accessed-from-multiple-threads) and I've even tried getting a new readable instance of the db from the helper for the query in a new thread, as in the code below:

```
        ContentValues deviceListEntry = new ContentValues();
        deviceListEntry.put(DeviceListDBEntry.NODE_ID, nodeID);
...

...

        String WHERE = DeviceListDBEntry.NODE_ID + " = ?";
        final String[] WHERE_ARG = {String.valueOf(nodeID)};
        SQLiteDatabase db = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();

        int listings = 0;
        try {
            //Update the device in the database DeviceList table
            listings = db.update(
                    DeviceListDBEntry.TABLE_NAME,
                    deviceListEntry,
                    WHERE,
                    WHERE_ARG
            );
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new ApiHandlerException("db.update(DeviceList, node " + nodeID + ")", e);
        }
        Log.e("updateDBdevice", " node " + device.getNodeID() + " listening = " + device.isListening());


        final String[] TABLE_COLUMNS = {
                DeviceListDBEntry.DEVICE_TYPE,
                DeviceListDBEntry.INTERVIEWED,
                DeviceListDBEntry.DEVICE_JSON
        };

        final String where = WHERE;
        new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                SQLiteDatabase db2 = dbHelper.getReadableDatabase();

                Cursor deviceEntry = db2.query(
                        DeviceListDBEntry.TABLE_NAME,   //FROM      DeviceList  Table
                        TABLE_COLUMNS,                  //SELECT    *           columns
                        where,                          //WHERE     nodeID =
                        WHERE_ARG,                      //args      nodeID
                        null,
                        null,
                        null
                );

                if (!deviceEntry.moveToFirst()) throw new ApiHandlerException("DeviceListDB no entry found - WHERE nodeID = " + nodeID);
                if (deviceEntry.getCount() > 1) throw new ApiHandlerException("DeviceListDB duplicate entries - WHERE nodeID = " + nodeID);

                String deviceJson = deviceEntry.getString(deviceEntry.getColumnIndexOrThrow(DeviceListDBEntry.DEVICE_JSON));

                Log.e("updateDBdevice retreive", " node " + nodeID + " JSON : " + deviceJson);
            }
        }).start();
```

I am using a Gson object to parse my `device` class to a `JSON` object which is stored in the DB. I know that this works when using the db.`insert(...)` method.

The query here is only there to see if the update was successful, because I found that explicit queries using other delayed threads (synchronised using a object lock and the same `SQLiteOpenHelper`) returned values that were not updated.

Is there an obvious thing I am missing or should I consider going to raw SQL commands on the db?

Comment: Have you checked the value of `listings` after the `update(....)` method is executed to see if any rows were affected ? Maybe your `WHERE` clause doesn't match any rows.

Comment: @Titus I can confirm that `listings` is equal to 1 after the `db.update()` command. So strange since the same `WHERE` and `WHERE_ARG` params are used for the update and query...

Comment: Maybe put your column names into constants.  Also your confusing the wack out of me by using all caps on non constant variables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My mistake, I found that I had actually not added the updated `JSON` object to the new entry. Subsequently the `deviceJson` column of the listing did not update, but a db.`update()` was executed...

Answer (score -1):

If "WHERE" clause has "text" column comparison then use single quotes around value. In your case try below line (notice single quotes around ?)

```
String WHERE = DeviceListDBEntry.NODE_ID + " = '?'";
```

Comment: As mentioned here  http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html#update(java.lang.String, android.content.ContentValues, java.lang.String, java.lang.String[])  the values are bound as `String`s, I don't think that quotes are needed

Comment: No need to add single quotes to where clause.